# Error while using index of one dataframe to acess the row of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have two distinct dataframes, df1 and df2. df1 is indexed by a complete serie of dates from an initial date to a final date; df2 is indexed from dates that are necessarily in df1, but its index is a subset of df1's index. I'm trying to iterate through df1.index and verify if the particular index value of df1 is present at df2 with the following code:

```
from datetime import timedelta
import datetime
import pandas as pd


for idx in df1.index:
    if idx in df2.index:
        print(df2.loc[idx])
```

The problem I'm facing is that some of the indexes of df2 are yield the if statement and some aren't. For instance:

```
sdate = datetime.date(2020, 5, 4)
edate = datetime.date(2020, 10, 1)
some_date = edate - timedelta(days=2)
# df1 with all the dates
df1 = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(sdate,edate-timedelta(days=1),freq='d'))
# df2 with only two dates (sdate and some_date)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=[sdate, some_date])
```

When I try to run the following code it yields `False`

```
df1.loc[some_date].name in df2.index
>>> False
```

Althought `some_date` clearly is in df2.index

```
some_date in df2.index
>>> True
```

It firstly appears that the return of `df1.loc[some_date].name` is incompatible in the comparision with df2.index, but when trying to run the following code, a different behavior is observed:

```
df1.loc[sdate].name in df2.index
>>> True
sdate in df2.index
>>> True
```

How does this really work?

Answer (score 0):

The error is because the data is of different types.
`df1.index` is `datetime` and `df2.index` is `date`.
Try like this:

```py
df1.index.normalize()
for idx in df2.index:
    if idx in df2.index:
        print(df2.loc[idx])
```

Or, replace the dates with datetimes:

```py
sdate = datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 4)
edate = datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 1)
```

Comment: This doesn't aswer the question regarding the behavior of the ```sdate```'s index and the ```some_date```'s index.

Comment: Can you explain what is the question then? I tested your code, and, at least with my version on python, lines `df1.loc[some_date].name in df2.index` and `df1.loc[sdate].name in df2.index` yield "KeyError". Comparing a `date` (sdate or some_date) with a `datetime` (df1.index) is not valid.